# How to use hibernate cascade on a given scenario?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

I have two table with OneToMany association which generated database structure with JoinColumn as below:

Table A
----------------------------
id(PK) | name | phone
----------------------------

Table B
----------------------------
id(PK) | street | a_id(FK)
----------------------------

My application scenario is that, I have to insert data in Table A first and Table B in second which has a foreign key of Table A. And the data insertion on those table is one at a time.

My question is how can I use hibernate cascade to insert data on table B which has a foreign key of table A?

One solution I found is:
-> Get the Table A Object
-> Add Table B Object on Table A Object
-> And insert Table A with cascade enabled on Table A

But I think its rather too expensive. Is there any other solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a manytoone in table B with "cascade = save-update". Thus every time you call save for object B which contains object A, it will saves object A first, followed by object B.

EDIT:

- get object A from database
- create object B
- set A to object B
- save object B

I guess that's the best I can do as the object A needs to be set first 
Sorry can't help you more :)

Comment: Your answer is best appropriate for my question. But I forgot to mention one thing, I will be having an existing data in Table A that needs to be associated with Table B. So, while inserting object B, I need to update object A each time when using "cascade = save-update". I thinks its more appropriate than my given solution, but is there any other simple solution for this scenario?

Comment: so from what you commented, I perceived that you want the table A to do the save instead of table B?

Comment: No. What I am saying is, save table B (have foreign key of table A) directly with association with table A. Currently, I only have an idea of saving table B by saving table A using cascade.

Comment: I don't understand why you have to update object A as if you already set B's foreign key, saving it will directly save/update the object specified in the foreign key.

Comment: Sorry to drag you in this misunderstanding. What I am saying is Object A will already exist in Table A, and I am confused on how to save Object B with foreign key.